# QuickJava for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, java, javascript

Is there something similar like QuickJava (Firefox Addon) for the Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

The latest chrome (10.x) has something called "Click to play" which lets chrome display a little icon where normally the flash/java/silverlight would be. The user has to click the area to play it.

You can enable that feature by going to 'about:flags' and activate it. After that you can choose under 'Options' -> 'Under the Hood' -> 'Content Settings' -> 'Plugins' what to do when Chrome encounters a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using HTML Content Blocker. It appears to behave quite similarly to the QuickJava addon for firefox but I haven't found a way to have quick access icons for at a glance feedback on whether something is enabled or not.

[HTML Content Blocker on Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-content-blocker/nobnkgabkebhhlgfddbemmefjnjnahoe?hl=en)

*I know it's a bit late but I though I'd provide an answer as I stumbled across this looking for the same thing